# How can i send docusign envelop to multiple recipient?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have one question regarding docusign api. I am using docusign api for electronic-sign. In my requirement the recipient view does not show on the docusign website and only show on my website where user can do e-sign for the document. Basically i done this. My question start now. How can i add two recipient on the document. I try it with single recipient but not know how to use multiple recipient. Here in two recipient(person) one is me and other is my client who purchase product from me. When i send this envelop to my client. It will come first to me and then after my sign will go to my client side and wait for its sign. How can i do this priorities also?

```
require_once './docusign-php-client/src/DocuSign_Client.php';
require_once './docusign-php-client/src/service/DocuSign_RequestSignatureService.php';
require_once './docusign-php-client/src/service/DocuSign_ViewsService.php';

$clientConfig = array(
        // Enter your Integrator Key, Email, and Password
        'integrator_key' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 'email' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 'password' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        // API version (v2 is latest) and environment (i.e. demo, www, etc)
        'version' => 'v2', 'environment' => 'demo'
);

// Instantiate client and call the Login API
$client = new DocuSign_Client($clientConfig);

// create service object and configure envelope settings, document(s), and recipient(s)
$service = new DocuSign_RequestSignatureService($client);

$emailSubject = "Please sign this document.";
$emailBlurb = "This is a document from Developer who test this docusign app. I would like to work with this.";

// add one signHere tab for the recipient located 100 pixels right and
// 150 pixels down from the top left corner of document's first page
$tabs1 = array( "signHereTabs" => array( 
                array( "documentId" => "2",
                    "pageNumber" => "1",
                    "xPosition" => "450",
                    "yPosition" => "233" )));

// $tabs2 = array( "signHereTabs" => array( 
//              array( "documentId" => "2",
//                  "pageNumber" => "1",
//                  "xPosition" => "130",
//                  "yPosition" => "233" )));


$signed_document_id = time();

// add a recipient and document to the envelope
$recipients = array( new DocuSign_Recipient( "1", "1", "I am", "my-email@my-email.in", $signed_document_id, 'signers', $tabs1) );
$documents = array( new DocuSign_Document("TEST.PDF", "1", file_get_contents("BCD.pdf")) , new DocuSign_Document("TEST.PDF", "2", file_get_contents("ABC.pdf")) );

// "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save as draft in your account   
$status = 'sent';

//*** Create and send the envelope with embedded recipient
$response = $service->signature->createEnvelopeFromDocument( $emailSubject, $emailBlurb, $status, $documents, $recipients, array() );

/**************************************************/
/*      Step- 3 Embadded sign iframe              */
/**************************************************/

$service = new DocuSign_ViewsService($client);

$envelopeId = $response->envelopeId;
$returnUrl = "https://demo.docusign.com;
$authMethod = "email";

$response = $service->views->getRecipientView(  $returnUrl,
                        $envelopeId, 
                        "i am", 
                        "my-email@my-email.in",
                        $signed_document_id,
                        $authMethod );

$sign_url = $response->url;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to sign your envelope first via your application? Then you want your customer to sign via your app? What do you mean by priorities? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Larry Yes, i want to sign first on my envelop via application and then i want to sign my customer can sign on that envelop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have two different people sign a document via DocuSign, where both are signing within your application.

This is called "embedded signing."

1. Create the envelope (signing request) with both signers. You must supply a *clientUserId* field for both recipients.
2. The result of envelope create is an envelope_id. Use it with the getRecipientView method to obtain the url for the first signer.
3. Redirect the signer to the url to sign. After signing, the signer's browser is re-directed back to your application. You can use an iframe but it is not recommended if there is any chance that people will be signing via a mobile/tablet device.
4. Later on, the other signer will log into your application. At that time, you can repeat the previous steps to enable the second signer to sign.

Remember that when you enable someone to sign from within your application, your app is responsible for authenticating the signer.

More information: see the [recipe for embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.